# Writing from Future of CachedThreadPool. Is my implementation incorrect?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, callable

I need help with my multithreading code.
I have a callable class which returns a value. I have a cachedThreadPool to submit ~60,000 tasks. I collect all the Futures in a List. After the ExecutiveService has shutdown, I loop through the list of Futures, and write the returned values using a bufferedWriter. Is this correct way of implementation?

```
ExecutorService execService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List<Future<ValidationDataObject<String, Boolean>>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < emailArrayList.size(); i++) {
    String emailAddress = emailArrayList.get(i);
    ValidateEmail validateEmail = new ValidateEmail(emailAddress);
    Future<ValidationDataObject<String, Boolean>> future = 
         execService.submit(validateEmail);
    futureList.add(future);
}

execService.shutdown();

for (Future<ValidationDataObject<String, Boolean>> future: futureList) {
    ValidationDataObject<String, Boolean> validationObject = future.get();
    bufferedWriter.write(validationObject.getEmailAddress() + "|"
             + validationObject.getIsValid());
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    bufferedWriter.flush();
}

if (execService.isTerminated()) bufferedWriter.close();
```

Should I using synchronized block for the bufferedWriter? I am thinking, It doesn't need to be synchronized because, I am using the bufferedWriter from the main Thread, right?

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Hi Gray - this thread has still not helped me solve my problem. I will when I find a solution to my problem. Thanks for asking. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact, that `executor.shutdown()` will most likely not do, what you believe it to do (it simply stops the Executor from accepting new Tasks, it will not wait for all tasks to terminate), your code looks fine.

You are right, there is no need for synchronization with respect to the writer, as you access it only single threaded.

There are things, that can be improved, though. Firstly, you are not doing a lot of Exception handling. `Future.get()` will throw an `ExecutionException`, if the `Callable` hits an `Exception`.

I'm not certain, how large the deviations in execution-time of your `Callables` are. Assume, there are notable deviations look at the following case: Say we submit `Callable`s A, B and C, you receive FutA, FutB and FutC. Calling the `get` methods will block until the calculation behind the `Future` is finished. In your setting, you might be waiting for FutA to complete, while FutB/FutC might already be finished and ready for writing. Worst case here is, that processing of A will delay writing for all 60000 tasks.

I think, I would go for another approach, where every `Callable` gets the reference to the same `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and instead of returning the result via `Future` writes the result into that queue. In this scenario, the ordering of the result is not dependent on the ordering of the `Callable`s but on the time, the `Callable`s finish execution. Whether or not this results in a speedup depends on your setting (especially time to write result and deviation in execution times of the `Callable`s).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! I will try your approach as well. True, I haven’t handled any exceptions actually. The problem is the Sysouts are printing all the data, however buffered writer is not writing 50% data. What would be causing that?

Comment: He _is_ waiting for the tasks to finish because that's what `Future.get()` does.

Comment: @Gray I did never say otherwise, just stated my assumption, that he is assuming, that executor.shutdown will wait for all threads to terminate. Could you please in future actually read the answers, you downvote?

Comment: Oh I read it @Jonathan.  I just think you are incorrect.  But it doesn't deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a cachedThreadPool to submit ~60,000 tasks.

Off the bat, a cached thread-pool and 60k tasks is a red flag.  That is going to start 60k threads which I doubt you really want.  You should use a fixed thread pool and vary the number of threads until you achieve a good balance of throughput versus overwhelming your server.  Maybe start with 2x the number of CPUs and then vary it depending on the server load.

You might also might consider using a fixed size queue which will limit the number of tasks outstanding although 60k tasks is fine unless those objects are heavy.

> I collect all the Futures in a List. After the ExecutiveService has shutdown, I loop through the list of Futures, and write the returned values using a bufferedWriter. Is this correct way of implementation?

Yes, that's a good pattern.  You don't show the writer being created but it is certainly fine for the main thread to own that.

> Should I using synchronized block for the bufferedWriter? I am thinking, It doesn't need to be synchronized because, I am using the bufferedWriter from the main Thread, right?

Right. No other threads are using it so that's fine.  It is a very typical pattern to have a writer thread managing the output of a multi-thread application.

One final comment is that you might want to look at the [`ExecutionCompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) which allows you to process the tasks as they finish instead of having to wait for them in order.  You might *require* the output to be in order in which case this isn't helpful but it's good technology to know about anyway.

Comment: Thanks Gray. I continue to face the same problem till now. The sysouts that I have in my tasks are printing all my tasks properly. But my buffered writer is not writing all my tasks in the file. It seems to be skipping 50% of task results. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Sorry @BharatNanwani.  No idea.  They should be there if the `call()` is returning them.